# HTTP Request Post Method & pass data in body

Tags: swift3

I'm trying to run a HTTP Request in Swift, to POST 2 parameters in Dictionary to a URL.

email & api_Key

How to pass Dictionary in Post Method..?

this code give me error..

Result -> ["status": {"status_code" = 3;"status_text" = "InvalidAccess.";}]

```
func postValidateDataInAPI(){
    let json: [String: Any] = ["email": "ravi.bokade@yudiz.com", "api_key": " "]
    do {
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options: .prettyPrinted)
        // create post request
        let url = URL(string: "http://www.eyeon.events/eyeon/rest/preregister_validate.php")!
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        // insert json data to the request
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest){ data, response, error in
            if error != nil{
                print("Error -> \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                let result = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as? [String:Any]

                print("Result -> \(result!)")

            } catch {
                print("Error -> \(error)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    } catch {
        print(error)
    }
}
```

Comment: how to pass Dictionary in "httpBody"..?